# Return Http Status Code=307 in Retrofit library on Android 12

Tags: android, retrofit2, cdn, cookiejar, http-status-code-307

Is there anything else to be done to access the **Internet on** **Android version 12**, because the program works on versions below Android 11, but it has a problem on version 12 and does not connect.
The service is run by the `Retrofit Library`, and that part is correct because it connects to the Internet in Android version 11.

**When I call the desired *API*, it returns `HTTP Status Code=307`, while it is done correctly in Android 11 and returns the response correctly, but in Android 12, it has a problem and returns `HTTP Status Code=307` and does not return me any response.**

> The desired api uses Cookie challenge in CDN

**in manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="*****">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

<application
    android:name="****.Application.Utility.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".Application.Activities.ActSplash"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Application.Activities.ActLogin"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**in network_security_config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user"
                tools:ignore="AcceptsUserCertificates" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**Retrofit Init:**

```
public class Retrofit {
private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

public static retrofit2.Retrofit retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl(AppController.ConvertDigitsToLatin(Variable.BASE_URL))
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
public static ISvcMethod Service = retrofit.create(ISvcMethod.class);
}
```

Comment: The `INTERNET` permission works fine on Android 12. My guess is that your problem lies with `<certificates src="user" tools:ignore="AcceptsUserCertificates" />`. But, that is just a guess.

Comment: This code works in versions 11 and below and there is no problem.This code works in versions 11 and below and there is no problem. If I remove this code, the problem will not be solved.@CommonsWare

Comment: What does 307 mean?

Comment: **HTTP Status Code=307** in rest api.This code only returns in Android 12, but in Android 11, it works properly and returns the desired response.@blackapps

Comment: The status code is 307. But what does 307 mean was and is the question. Third time i ask.